# Ruby on Rails, How to add projects to users/show.html.erb with has_many names :through blueprints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, activerecord

For each project that a user has blueprints for, I want to show the projects name and link to the project_path. Thanks.

These are my ActiveRecords

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :name
  has_many :blueprints
  has_many :projects, :through => :blueprints
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :name
  has_many :blueprints
  has_many :users, :through => :blueprints
end

class Blueprint < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :name, :project_id, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end
```

My Users show Controller

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @user }
  end
end
```

My Views/Users/Show.html.erb Table

```
    <table>
      <tr>
        <% @projects.each do |p| %>
          <td><%= p.name %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For each project that a user has blueprints for, I want to show the projects name and link to the project_path.

For these requirements, you can remove the `@project` assignment from your action. You need to look at the `blueprints` relation for `@user`, and get the associated `project` for each of those `blueprints`.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <% @user.blueprints.each do |blueprint| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to blueprint.project.name, project_path(blueprint.project) %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```